# Securing Endpoint in Django including Generic Relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In a simplified version i have 3 classes

in the first app (named: appBasic):

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

```
class ClassB(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    specific_B = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

in another app (appSpec)

```
class ClassBSpec(models.Model):
    class_b = GenericRelation(ClassB, related_name='class_b')
    class_a = ForeignKey(ClassA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

using these classes i build the endpoints using NestedRouters form the rest_framework_nested to get to:

```
/appSpec/class_b_spec/
/appSpec/class_b_spec/<pk>/
/appSpec/class_b_spec/<class_b_spec_pk>/class_b/
/appSpec/class_b_spec/<class_b_spec_pk>/class_b/<pk>/
```

**my goal is to protect these endpoints and allow post,get,put,patch request only for instances, which belong (via *class_a*) to the current user.**

To secure the first two endpoints i add the following method in the ClassBSpecSerializer:

```
def validate_class_a(self, class_a):
    user_id = self.context['user_id']
    if classs_a.user.id != user_id:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('No class_a with given ID found for this user')
    return class_a
```

However, i cannot do the same for the other two endpoints,

```
/appB/class_b_spec/<class_b_spec_pk>/class_b/
/appB/class_b_spec/<class_b_spec_pk>/class_b/<pk>/
```

because here i am dealing with a generic relation-ship

What i have implemented for now is to override the ViewSet for ClassB in the second app (appSpec) such as:

```
from appBasic.views import classBViewSet as BasicClassBViewSet
class ClassBViewSet(BasicClassBViewSet):
    class_b_spec_queryset = ClassBSpec.objects.filter(classA__user_id=self.request.user.id)
    class_b_spec = get_object_or_404(class_b_spec_querset=self.kwargs['class_b_spec_pk']
    return class_b_spec.class_b.all()
```

like that i can ensure that i get a 404 error when i am at this endpoint:

```
/appB/class_b_spec/<class_b_spec_pk>/class_b/
```

and try to access class_b instances belonging to another user (via class_b_spec.class_a.user)

however, what is not possible to prevent a post-method.
at this endpoint i can basically add instances of class_b to the class_b_spec instance belonging to another user.
but i cannot validate somehow the user, because with the generic relationship, defined above as specific_B, i cannot access specific_B.class_a.user.id, because the generic relationship does not know that there is a class_a field.

i dont find any solution to that problem.
i feel that i have to add a ForeignKey to User for the classB class, but then this information is somehow redundant.

in here [Serializing a generic relation in django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721923/serializing-a-generic-relation-in-django-rest-framework)
it is proposed to add some logic to the classB serializer. But  i wanted to keep that serializer as it is.

However, i will have the field class_a in all Content_Types, to which i want to make a link in the class_b object. But i dont know how to make use of that?